# Cell, vector, or array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am a newbie in MATLAB from the Python world.

I have been having trouble with the `cell`, `vector`, or `array` in MATLAB.

How does one compare them and what are the differences?

Answer (score 2):

A **vector** is a one dimensional array. It can be a column or a row vector, depends on how you define it. Each element of the vector is a scalar.

A **matrix** consists of a sequence of column or row vectors. Each element of the matrix is a scaler.

You can think **cell** as a matrix where each element can be a vector or a matrix or even a cell. It is not demanted that all your vector must have the same dimension. The same logic follows for the matrices and the cells. Finally, in a cell you can have a combination of these structures.

```
M_a = ones(2); % 2x2 matrix
M_b = ones(4); % 4x4 matrix
v_b = ones(1,4); % row vector
v_a = ones(5,1); % column vector

myCell = cell(2); % a 2x2 cell array

myCell{1} = M_a;
myCell{2} = M_b;
myCell{3} = v_a;
myCell{4} = v_b;

myCell = 

    [2x2 double]    [5x1 double]
    [4x4 double]    [1x4 double]

myCell{4} = myCell ;

myCell = 

    {2x2 cell  }    [5x1 double]
    [4x4 double]    [1x4 double]
```

Comment: i have a follow up question. suppose i have an matrix of 3x10 numbers, or i could also have a cell of 3x10 numbers, whose operations will be faster, the matrix or cell ? thanks.

Comment: Basically, I am not sure that you can do operations between cell matrices. So there can not be a comparison. Maybe, you should transform your cell to mat, `cell2mat`, and then do operations. But again this follows the case when the cell elements dimensions are consistent, e.g., when you have scalars for each cell. In this ideal situation matrix operations may be faster because you do not have to do any transformations.